2D Square Collision Correction issue detecting which direction
I've just started getting into 2D game development and have been experimenting with some 2D collision and correction logic in canvas. I'm trying to debug this block of code and understand why it is not triggering any intersections vertically except when you flip the comparison sign for the previous states comparison to find which direction it comes in at but with them flipped it reads weird and makes no sense to me.
// this sets up a scenario where the player is intersecting the obstacle and
// its previousY tells us it should be colliding from the top of the obstacle with the bottom of the player
const player = {
  x: 100,
  y: 322,
  width: boxSize,
  height: boxSize,
  previousX: 100,
  previousY: 300
}

const obstacle = createObstacle(
  100,
  300,
  30,
  70
)

function checkCollision(player, obstacle) {
  const playerTop = player.y
  const playerBottom = player.y + player.height

  const obstacleTop = obstacle.y
  const obstacleBottom = obstacle.y + obstacle.height

  // broad collision (this is triggered no problem)
  if (
    player.x + player.width > obstacle.x
    && player.x < obstacle.x + obstacle.width
    && player.y + player.height > obstacle.y
    && player.y < obstacle.y + obstacle.height
  ) {
    console.log(`Player Bottom: ${playerBottom}, Player Top: ${playerTop}`);
    console.log(`Previous Bottom: ${player.previousY + player.height}, Previous Top: ${player.previousY}`);
    console.log(`Obstacle Top: ${obstacleTop}, Obstacle Bottom: ${obstacleBottom}`);

    if (
      playerBottom >= obstacleTop &&
      player.previousY + player.height < obstacleTop
    ) {
      console.log('hitting top of obstacle')
    } else if (
      playerTop <= obstacleBottom &&
      player.previousY > obstacleBottom 
    ) {
      console.log('hitting bottom of obstacle')
    }

  }
}

checkCollision(player, obstacle)
```


The origin of an HTML Canvas object, and nearly all 2d engine implementations,  is the top left at (0,0) with Y increasing down.
The one, maybe more, exception is Scratch that has the origin in the middle of the screen and positive Y is up.

Lines like const playerBottom = player.y + player.height; and const obstacleBottom = obstacle.y + obstacle.height; make it appear as though this code was already written for a "y increases downwards" coordinate system. Is there a specific line or set of lines you've identified that are not written correctly for this coordinate convention?

@DMGregory It is in the question "intersections vertically except when you flip the comparison sign" That is a classic description of Y inversion.  "Is there a specific line", You missed the comment: "(this is triggered no problem)" This is an accurate answer to the question as asked.
